Errors raised in console after downloading code from git
I recently downloaded a zip file from git and I extracted all files and opened in VS Code and as per instructions in readme.md file I tried to install all dependencies but it shows like this:
npm install

up to date, audited 1797 packages in 15s

120 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

132 vulnerabilities (1 low, 104 moderate, 23 high, 4 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

After that I also tried to fix that as per the errors like npm audit fix or npm audit fix --force still it shows all those.
Looking for help fixing these errors.

Those are warnings, not errors. The "up to date" message says the package got installed successfully in a previous call to npm install.

The "132 vulnerabilities" message means that the project is using dependencies that have known vulnerabilities, and should ideally be updated. For testing purposes and getting started, you can ignore them, but the authors of the package should really try to address them.

Does this answer your question? How to fix npm vulnerabilities manually?

This is actually pretty common in npm, especially if the app is using outdated packages. These are not considered errors and they will probably not affect you in any way while executing the app, you can even get those if you start a clean project. Consider them warnings that the npm tells you "Heeey, some of your packages are actually outdated or can somehow be abused by people who mean to do harm in your app"
Tip: Many of those vulnerabilities will disappear if you update the packages, but especially on big projects i suggest you not to, it is almost certain you will get compatibility problems between packages.
